# FlatMap function on a CoGrouped RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to use a flatmap function on the cogroupedRDD which has the signature:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>
```

my flatmap function is as follows:

```
static FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>,Row> setupF = new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>,Row>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Row> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>> row) {
        }};
```

But i am getting compilation error . I am sure it must be a syntactical issue which I am not able to understand.

Full Code:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>> coGroupedRDD = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2);
JavaRDD<Row> jd = coGroupedRDD.flatmap(setupF);
 static FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>,Row> setupF = new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>,Row>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Row> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>> row) {
        //logic
}};
```

Error:

```
The method flatmap(FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String,Tuple2<Iterable<Row>,Iterable<Row>>>,Row>) is undefined for the type JavaPairRDD<String,Tuple2<Iterable<Row>,Iterable<Row>>>
```

Comment: why don't you use Java 8 lambdas? it takes care of Type inference.

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: I just tried the same thing but i'm not getting any error. wondering why. i'm using java8

Comment: working for me. Could you please post your complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wild guess here, maybe the reason is that you write your code against Spark 1.6 API but you actually use Spark 2.0 dependency? API differs between these two releases.

Spark 1.6 API [FlatMapFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) method signature:

```
Iterable<R> call(T t)
```

Spark 2.0 API [FlatMapFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) method signature:

```
Iterator<R> call(T t)
```

So try change you code to this:

```
new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>>, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Row> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Iterable<Row>, Iterable<Row>>> row) {
        //...
        }
};
```

or using Java 8 lambda version:

```
   coGroupedRDD
   .flatMap(t -> {
        List<Row> result = new ArrayList<>();
        //...use t._1, t._2._1, t._2._2 to construct the result list
        return result.iterator();
    });
```

Comment: I used the lambda version and it is working just fine.. thanks Max